# New line not showing in text file created by ColdFusion

Tags: text, coldfusion

I added a new line to a text file I generated using `chr(10)&chr(13)`. I sent a copy of the text file to my email and dropped a copy in a folder. The one I receive in my email is well-formatted while the one in the folder doesn't have the new line inserted so it's all muddled up. What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: we'll need to see the code you're using to generate the file.  Also you should be using Chr(13) & Chr(10) as line delimiters, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

Used `char(13)&char(10)` (carriage return, line feed) as opposed to `char(10)&char(13)` (line feed, carriage return).